# wp_query() while statement not working

Tags: wordpress, while-loop

I am trying to run a wp_query() and the query runs but the while statement doesn't execute.

```
global $current_user;
                                get_currentuserinfo();
                                $user_id = $current_user->ID;

$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'profile', 'posts_author' => $user_id ) );

if ($query->have_posts()) : while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();


if(isset($_GET['post'])) {

if($_GET['post'] == $post->ID) {

ob_start();
the_content();
$old_content = ob_get_clean();
$new_content = strip_tags($old_content);
    $current_post = $post->ID;

    $pharaohs_cover_image = esc_url(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pharaohs_cover_image',true));
    $pharaohs_fullname = esc_attr(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pharaohs_fullname',true));
    $pharaohs_nickname = esc_attr(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pharaohs_nickname',true));
    $pharaohs_gender = esc_attr(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pharaohs_gender',true));
    $pharaohs_interestedIn = esc_attr(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pharaohs_interestedIn',true));
    $pharaohs_likes = esc_attr(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pharaohs_likes',true));
    $pharaohs_profile_picture = esc_url(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'pharaohs_profile_picture',true));




}

}
```

endwhile;
 endif;

Any assistance will be highly appreciated, thank you in advance...

Comment: Because you're running the while statement in the if statement, it's not needed.

Comment: Code seems... Did you try debugging from inside the while loop by printing or setting die ?